# Autofac resolve instace in current web request scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have class to setup Autofac in my WebApi project, it's look like:

```cs
public static class Bootstraper
    {
        private static IContainer _container { get; set; }

        public static void Init()
        {
            var configuration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // register WebAPI   
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(configuration);
            builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(configuration);

            // register MVC
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());

            // register model class
            builder.RegisterType<Foo>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterType<FooMessage>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();

            var container = builder.Build();

            // setup WebApi Autofac resolver
            var resolverAPI = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            configuration.DependencyResolver = resolverAPI;

            // setup MVC Autofac resolver
            var resolverMVC = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolverMVC);

            _container = container;
        }

        public static T Resolve<T>()
        {
            return _container.Resolve<T>();
        }

        public static T ResolveInScope<T>()
        {
            // where scope shoud by disposed?
            var scope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag);
            return scope.Resolve<T>();
        }
    }
```

**Foo** and **FooMessage** class:

```cs
 public class FooMessage
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request {get; private set; }
        public Foo Foo { get; private set; }

        public FooMessage(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, Foo fooo)
        {
            Request = requestMessage;
            Foo = fooo;
        }
    }

 public class Foo
    {
        public static int counter = 0;

        public int Index { get; private set; }
        public Foo()
        {
            Index = counter++;
        }
    }
```

To show my problem, I prepared example controller

```cs
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        private FooMessage fooMessage;
        private Foo foo;

        public ValuesController(FooMessage fm, Foo fooo)
        {
            fooMessage = fm;
            foo = fooo;
        }


        // GET api/values
        public bool Get()
        {
            // it works but create new Foo object (resolvedFoo.Index > foo.Index)
            var resolvedFoo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Foo>();

            // throw the exception 
            var resolvedFoo2 = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(Foo)) as Foo;

            // throw the Exception
            var resolvedFoo3 = Bootstraper.Resolve<Foo>();

            // it works but create new Foo object (resolvedFoo.Index > foo.Index)
            // and I don't now when dispose created scope
            var resolvedFoo4 = Bootstraper.ResolveInScope<Foo>();


            if (resolvedFoo.Index != foo.Index || resolvedFoo.Index != fooMessage.Foo.Index)
                return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
```

When the ValuesController is created the Index properties in foo and fooMessage.Foo has the same value, it works greate. I need resolve Foo, FooMessage and especially HttpRequestMessage in my bussines logic (InstancePerRequest) but I can't use bussines constructor to do this. For my purpose best solution would by use Bootstraper.Resolve() but it throw the exception:

> An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException'
>   occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No scope with a Tag matching
>   'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance
>   was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as
>   per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component
>   (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request
>   dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or
>   ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container
>   itself.

Please, help me to understand how it shoud work.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? I'm struggling with a similar problem, wanting to resolve an instance in the current web request scope, but `BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag)` creates a new scope and then a new non-shared instance.

Comment: Since some time has passed , if you found a solution it would be helpful for others to know how to resolve this .